# Multiple rlib candidates found

Tags: rust, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile an application that needs `mem*` functions, so I added this to my `Cargo.toml`:

```
compiler_builtins = { version = "0.1.35", features = ["mem"] }
```

I'm getting a compilation error that says:

```
error[E0465]: multiple rlib candidates for `compiler_builtins` found
  |
  = note: candidate #1: target/x86_64-unknown-uefi/debug/deps/libcompiler_builtins-a0e318c45dffdc3f.rlib
  = note: candidate #2: target/x86_64-unknown-uefi/debug/deps/libcompiler_builtins-86a9a51317aff18e.rlib
```

Replacing `compiler_builtins` with the deprecated `rlibc` fixes this problem, but I'd rather not use deprecated packages.

Comment: Try `cargo update` or `cargo tree -d` to see potential conflicts

Comment: @Caio `cargo update` quits cleanly and `cargo tree -d` doesn't display any conflicts

Comment: I've got similar  exception ```error[E0465]: multiple rmeta candidates for `compiler_builtins` found```. Can't find any solution

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this error today

```
error[E0465]: multiple rmeta candidates for `<package_name>` found
```

It turns out I had different versions specified for this package between `[dependencies]` and `[dev-dependencies]` section in the `Cargo.toml` file.